# Como atualizar a uma coluna de outra tabela automaticamente ao fazer um update utilizando trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

```
CREATE TABLE TB_Empregado(
nome varchar(50),
rg int primary key, 
cpf varchar (11),
salario money
)
---

CREATE TABLE TB_Dependente(
rg_responsavel int constraint fk_TB_Dependente_Empregado references TB_Empregado(rg),
nome_dependente varchar (50),
data_nascimento date,
relacao varchar(45),
sexo char(1),
primary key (rg_responsavel, nome_dependente)
)
```

Preciso criar uma TRIGGER que atualize automaticamente o RG do responsável de um dependente sempre que o mesmo (RG do empregado) for atualizado na tabela empregado

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer um update de uma chave estrangeira assim, isso causaria problemas de integridade, pois se você atualizar o RG da tabela TB_Empregado, a referência na tabela TB_Dependente deixaria de existir.

Existe duas formas de resolver isso:

1. Realizar o UPDATE nas duas tabelas usando BEGIN TRANSACTION;
2. Recriar a chave estrangeira usando a condição "ON UPDATE CASCADE";

Existe uma pergunta parecida com a sua no fórum global que pode ser que te ajude em alguma outra dúvida posterior.

[link da pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255151/sql-server-updating-foreign-key-referential-integrity)